# LaTex macro with \begin and \end parts split in different loops

Tags: beamer, macros, loops, pgffor, overpic

Consider the minimal working example below that progressively superimposes (using the `overpic` package) images contained in a pdf file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\onslide<1->{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=1]{MyPDF}
\onslide<2->{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=2]{MyPDF}
\onslide<3->{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=3]{MyPDF}
\end{overpic}}
\end{overpic}}
\end{overpic}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to shorten this code using a macro that takes as arguments the number of pages and the name of the pdf file. Ideally, the reduced code should look like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\MyMacro{3}{MyPDF}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I tried to realize this using two for loops (using the `pgffor` package) as follows

```
\newcommand{\MyMacro}[2]{
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\onslide<\n->\{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=\n]{#2}}
\foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{\end{overpic}\}}
}
```

However, this approach does not work. I think that the main issue is that the `\begin{overpic}` and the `\end{overpic}` parts are split into two separate loops. I cannot figure out a way to make it work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it can be done by means of a recursive loop:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{overpic}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\MyMacro[3]{%
  \onslide<#1->{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=#1]{#3}%
    \ifnum#1<\numexpr#2\relax
      \exchange{\expandafter\MyMacro\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}}%
    \fi
  \end{overpic}}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\MyMacro{1}{3}{MyPDF}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This yields a pdf-file which looks like this

[image]

whereby

**MyPDF.pdf** looks like this:

[image]

---

---

If `\foreach` is from the TikZ-package/pgffor-package, then the approach presented by you can't work out because each iteration takes place within its own local scope, i.e., you get something like

```latex
\begingroup
\onslide<1->\{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=1]{MyPDF}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\onslide<2->\{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=2]{MyPDF}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\onslide<2->\{\begin{overpic}[width=\textwidth,page=2]{MyPDF}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\end{overpic}\}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\end{overpic}\}
\endgroup
\begingroup
\end{overpic}\}
\endgroup
```

Besides this:

`{` and `}` are explicit character tokens of category 1(begin group)/2(end group) while `\{` and `\}` are control-symbol-tokens with whatsoever definition.

Thus you cannot replace `{` by `\{` and `}` by `\}` and expect argument-group-matching to work out.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: @Cav6897 I just did an edit as I overlooked that with `\ifnum`'s second number you need to ensure that in any case expansion stops before searching for matching `\else` and `\fi`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try add option `[parse=true]` for `\foreach`

```tex
\foreach[parse=true] \n in ....
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: pgfmanual.pdf says: *`/pgf/foreach/parse={<boolean>}` -  If this key is set to true the upper bound in the loop will be fed into `\pgfmathparse`. This allows to use complex expressions as the upper bound. However, the expression must be safe for evaluation in `\pgfmathparse`.* `parse=true` does not resolve the issue of each iteration of a `\foreach`-loop taking place in its own local scope.